# Bind first element of nested list to the subsequent elements of nested list

Tags: r

I have a nested list and I would like to bind the first element of each list to the  rest of the elements of that nested list. (Do this for each list in the entire set)

Here are the first 2 higher level lists. The goal is to output a dataframe with two columns. Column 1 being the first row, Column 2 being the subsequent rows.

Simplified Version:

```
list(c("Location1", 
       "Location1_Bid1", 
       "Location1_Bid2", 
       "Location1_Bid3"), 
     c("Location2", 
     "Location2_Bid1", 
     "Location2_Bid2", 
     "Location2_Bid3"),
     c("Location3", 
     "Location3_Bid1", 
     "Location3_Bid2", 
     "Location3_Bid3",
     "Location3_Bid4")
     , c("Location4", 
     "Location4_Bid1", 
     "Location4_Bid2"))
```

For example:

```
Location        |  Bid
"Location1"     | "Location1_Bid1"
"Location1"     | "Location1_Bid2"
"Location1"     | "Location1_Bid3"
"Location2"     | "Location2_Bid1"
"Location2"     | "Location2_Bid2"
"Location2"     | "Location2_Bid3"
"Location3"     | "Location3_Bid1"
"Location3"     | "Location3_Bid2"
"Location3"     | "Location3_Bid3"
"Location3"     | "Location3_Bid4"
"Location4"     | "Location4_Bid1"
"Location4"     | "Location4_Bid2"
```

Comment: Can you please share you sample input with `dput()` so it is copy-pasteable? It would be a real pain to read in to R what you've  put in your question.

Comment: Alternatively, just create a simplified example of the data. For example, `lst <- list(a = list(...), b = list(...))` - it's probably possible to create the gist of the problem with a simplified list structure.

Comment: I don't want a link and a download, just some copy-pasteable R syntax. Something like `dput(your_list[1:2])`, or if that's too long `dput(lapply(your_list[1:2], "[", 1:4))`.

Comment: working on simplified version now @JasonAizkalns

Comment: @Gregor Is that better?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I'm still working on simplified version

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function that does what you want and use `lapply` to do it to each list item:

```
foo = function(x) cbind(x[1], x[-1])
result = lapply(your_list, foo)
```

Calling your simple example "simple":

```
lapply(simple, foo)
# [[1]]
#      [,1]        [,2]            
# [1,] "Location1" "Location1_Bid1"
# [2,] "Location1" "Location1_Bid2"
# [3,] "Location1" "Location1_Bid3"
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1]        [,2]            
# [1,] "Location2" "Location2_Bid1"
# [2,] "Location2" "Location2_Bid2"
# [3,] "Location2" "Location2_Bid3"
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1]        [,2]            
# [1,] "Location3" "Location3_Bid1"
# [2,] "Location3" "Location3_Bid2"
# [3,] "Location3" "Location3_Bid3"
# [4,] "Location3" "Location3_Bid4"
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1]        [,2]            
# [1,] "Location4" "Location4_Bid1"
# [2,] "Location4" "Location4_Bid2"
```

These are matrices, not data frames. You could use `cbind.data.frame` instead of just `cbind` if you want data frames out. You could also add column names as in your sample output, e.g.

```
foo = function(x) cbind.data.frame(Location = x[1], Bid = x[-1])
```

Comment: I was able to get the Matrix solution to work but when I use cbind.data.frame() I get the error:  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: That's strange, the `cbind.data.frame` version works for me on both your simple example and the data you had use `dput` on and since removed. If you can find a minimal example where it fails I can help debug, but for now I only see it working.

Comment: I get the same error when I run it on the "simple example", idk

Comment: Maybe some packages are masking things? I just restarted R and ran nothing but the `foo` definition, the `simple` definition, and `lapply(simple, foo)` and it works fine.

Comment: I've restarted R. Taken out all packages except pdftools and stringr. Do you know any alternate functions that do the same thing? When I run the debugger it seems to point to a problem in my data.frame() function.

Comment: I get identical results if I use `data.frame(Location = x[1], Bid = x[-1])` or `cbind.data.frame(Location = x[1], Bid = x[-1])` or `as.data.frame(cbind(Location = x[1], Bid = x[-1]))` as the body of `foo`. These all work for your `simple` example. I can only reproduce your error if I add in a list item that has length `1`, in which case the `cbind.data.frame` and `data.frame` versions fail, but `as.data.frame(cbind())` still works (with a 1-column result, of course). Maybe check your lengths, `which(lengths(your_list) == 1)`

Comment: For some reason as.data.frame(cbind(Location = x[1], Bid = x[-1]))  seems to work but I still can't export this as a csv.

Comment: I do have a few list items of length 1

Comment: Can't export *what* as a CSV? Are you trying to combine these all into one data frame? (I wish you would have said so sooner...) And your simplified example doesn't have lists of length 1, so does it work on that???

Comment: Haha yeah I'm trying combine these all into one data frame. Also, I removed the items of length 1 and the other methods worked just like you said.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extra help and guidance. I used the  bind_rows() from dplyr and it seems to work alright.